# Add image to GridView's Cell

Tags: asp.net

I want to add image to GridView cell with below code but doesn't show image

```
//aspx
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="image">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" />
      </ItemTemplate>
```

```
//.cs -> In page_Load

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
      Image img = (Image)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("img");
      img.ImageUrl = path of image;
 }//for
```

Comment: what is path of image ? might be some url issue there..

Comment: Did you try to debug and see if the `for` loop is called?

Comment: the path is correct,i test it and for called,i check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RowDataBound` event to change something inside a GridView Row.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if this row is a row with Data (not Header or Footer)
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // find your Image control in the Row
        Image image = ((Image)e.Row.FindControl("img"));
        // set the path of image
        img.ImageUrl = "path of image";     
    }
}
```

Or you can use a `foreach` statment to loop in Rows collection and change the path of image. this code could be on the Page_Load event.

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{ 
    // check if this row is a row with Data (not Header or Footer)
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // find your Image control in the Row
        Image image = ((Image)row.FindControl("img"));
        // set the path of image
        img.ImageUrl = "path of image";     
    }
}
```

### Edits

You cannot set the image out of the solution. Do to this, you have to create an Handler (.ashx file) and pass the name of your image on C: and return the a byte[], something like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\" + context.Request["image"]);
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageBytes);
}
```

And on your page, set it by handler passing a `image` parameter in url:

```
Image image = ((Image)row.FindControl("img"));
img.ImageUrl = "ImageHandler.ashx?image=1.png";
```

Comment: This would change all of the images in the row. This may not be the desired effect. As in OP's sample, you may want to alter this find the specific cell.

Comment: In that case, you can specify the cell with `Cells` collection, sample: `row.Cells[1].FindControl("img")`.

Comment: If you add an image on the same folder of the aspx file and set only the file name, e.g.: `image.png`, it works! are you sure the path of image is right?

Comment: I add image to the same folder of the aspx file and set the file, works properly but when i e.g set `c:/1.png` or `c://1.png` or `c:\1.png` or 'c:\\1.png' doesn't work

Comment: Look my edits. You have to create a Handler on this case to get the image out of the solution folder (e.g.: C:, C:\image..)

Answer (score 0):

The event `Page_Load` fires before the GridView databinds or creates itself. If they're all going to be the same image, why not just set that path to in the ItemTemplate? If it's because you don't know the path until you get into the code behind, you could bind the ImageUrl in the template to a custom property and then just set that property in the Page_Load and then populate the property. Otherwise, any changes you want to make will need to be done in the RowDataBound event.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly give path to image from database

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Imageurl") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
```

or give url in alt tag and in rowdatabound use it.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    Image image1 = ((Image)e.Row.FindControl("img"));
    img.ImageUrl = image1.Alt; // You can check for path here if no image found     
}
```

Using loop through gridview is not proper way as well as it decrease the performance